# dropdownlist in a gridview returns to default vaule after selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, postback, autopostback

I have a dropdownlist in a gridview, also have a a linkbutton, button and panel. as shown below. when i select a value in dropdown list it returns to default

I have tried to put the gridview in an updatepanel and set the enable viewstate of the dropdrownlist to true and that did help, please any one with suggestions.

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="box" 



        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="pText" align="center">
                <b>Treatment Details<br />
                </b>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CssClass="grey1">Basic Billing</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

   <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" Visible="False">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
        style="height: 88px; width: 294px">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" class="grey1" colspan="2" style="height: 13px">
            .:Basic Billing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td class="pText" style="height: 19px">
            Enter policy Number:</td>
        <td style="height: 19px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textfields">       </asp:TextBox>

           </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="pText" style="height: 19px">
            Enter Number of Basic Billing Item:</td>
        <td style="height: 19px">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="textfields"></asp:TextBox>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" Text="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
                AllowSorting="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" CssClass="MyGridView" 
                OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
                OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="750px">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S/N">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpOutp" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpOutp_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" OnLoad="Load_OutpDetail">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUnit" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txteffdate" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" Height="15px" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Price">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalP" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblPageHeaderII_new" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F4F4F4" />
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="No Data Returned !"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>

        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code behind

```
Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Panel3.Visible = True
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Try
        Dim params() As SqlParameter = {New SqlParameter("@PolicyNumber", Trim(txtPolicy.Text)), _
                                    New SqlParameter("@IPAddress", Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")), _
                                   New SqlParameter("@PostedBy", Session("HMOUser"))}

        Dim retValue As Data.DataRow = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connstring, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "HMO_Enrollee_CheckByPolicyNumber", params).Tables(0).Rows(0)

        If retValue Is Nothing Then

            lblmsg.Text = "Invalid Policy Number"
            txtPolicy.Text = ""

        Else
            Session("Enr") = retValue.Table.Rows(0).Item("Enrollee_Number")

Catch ex As Exception
                HMO_BLL.WriteLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)
            End Try


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        lblmsg.Text = "Invalid Policy Number"
    End Try

Dim nos As Integer() = New Integer(Convert.ToInt32(txtItemNo.Text) - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To nos.Length - 1
        nos(i) = i + 1
    Next
    GridView1.DataSource = nos
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub

Public Sub Load_OutpDetail(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'If Not IsPostBack Then


    Try
        Dim ds As Data.DataSet = DAL.HMO_Outp_Detail_drpdown()
        Dim Li As ListItem
        Li = New ListItem
        Li.Value = "0"
        Li.Text = "-- Select --"

        Dim drpOutp As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)

        drpOutp.AppendDataBoundItems = True
        drpOutp.Items.Clear()
        drpOutp.Items.Add(Li)

        If Not ds Is Nothing And ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With drpOutp
                .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                .DataTextField = "OutpDetail"
                .DataValueField = "OutpID"
                .DataBind()
                .SelectedIndex = 0
            End With
        Else
            drpOutp.Enabled = False

        End If
        ds.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        HMO_BLL.WriteLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
    'End If
End Sub
Protected Sub drpOutp_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            Dim drpOutp As DropDownList = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("drpOutp"), DropDownList)
            Dim lblEffDate As Label = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("lblEffDate"), Label)

            'Dim drpOutp As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)

            Dim params() As SqlParameter = {New SqlParameter("@OutpID", drpOutp.SelectedValue), _
                                            New SqlParameter("@ProviderID", HiddenField1.Value)}
            Dim retValue As Data.DataRow = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connstring, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "HMO_Outp_Fetch_price", params).Tables(0).Rows(0)
            lblEffDate.Text = retValue.Table.Rows(0).Item("Uprice")
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        HMO_BLL.WriteLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank you

---

@Tim Thank you, this was really helpful i did what you said code below. but i need some data to bind on a label in the same gridview that is y i have SelectedIndexChanged event-handler. I am still having a little challenge i want to be able to bind data on labels in d row which d dropdownlist where a value was selected but what i have seem to bind to the label on the first row only, regardless of the dropdownlist that was selected. Any pointers??

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="box" 



    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="pText" align="center">
            <b>Treatment Details<br />
            </b>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CssClass="grey1">Basic Billing</asp:LinkButton>
   </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

       <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" Visible="False">
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
    style="height: 88px; width: 294px">
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="grey1" colspan="2" style="height: 13px">
        .:Basic Billing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
           <td class="pText" style="height: 19px">
            Enter policy Number:</td>
    <td style="height: 19px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textfields">       </asp:TextBox>

       </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="pText" style="height: 19px">
        Enter Number of Basic Billing Item:</td>
    <td style="height: 19px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="textfields"></asp:TextBox>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" Text="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"
            AllowSorting="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" CssClass="MyGridView" 
            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
            OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="750px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S/N">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpOutp" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpOutp_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" OnLoad="Load_OutpDetail">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Price">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUnit" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteffdate" runat="server" CssClass="textfields" Height="15px" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Price">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalP" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <controlstyle bordercolor="LightGray" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblPageHeaderII_new" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F4F4F4" />
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="No Data Returned !"></asp:Label>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        &nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

code behind

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Try
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then


            Dim ctrl As Control = e.Row.FindControl("drpOutp")


            If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ddl As DropDownList = TryCast(ctrl, DropDownList)


                Dim ds As Data.DataSet = DAL.HMO_Outp_Detail_drpdown()
                Dim Li As ListItem
                Li = New ListItem
                Li.Value = "0"
                Li.Text = "-- Select --"



                ddl.AppendDataBoundItems = True
                ddl.Items.Clear()
                ddl.Items.Add(Li)

                If Not ds Is Nothing And ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    With ddl
                        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        .DataTextField = "OutpDetail"
                        .DataValueField = "OutpID"
                        .DataBind()
                        .SelectedIndex = 0
                    End With
                Else
                    ddl.Enabled = False

                End If
                ds.Dispose()
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        HMO_BLL.WriteLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try

End Sub
Protected Sub drpOutp_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = TryCast(sender, DropDownList)

        For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            Dim ctrl As Control = TryCast(gvRow.FindControl("drpOutp"), DropDownList)
            If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = DirectCast(ctrl, DropDownList)


                Dim params() As SqlParameter = {New SqlParameter("@OutpID", ddl.SelectedValue), _
                                                New SqlParameter("@ProviderID", HiddenField1.Value)}
                Dim retValue As Data.DataRow = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connstring, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "HMO_Outp_Fetch_price", params).Tables(0).Rows(0)
                Dim UnitP As Label = TryCast(gvRow.FindControl("lblUnit"), Label)
                UnitP.Text = retValue.Table.Rows(0).Item("Uprice")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        HMO_BLL.WriteLog(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim nos As Integer() = New Integer(Convert.ToInt32(txtItemNo.Text) - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To nos.Length - 1
        nos(i) = i + 1
    Next
    GridView1.DataSource = nos
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using DropDownList's onLoad event? You should use Page_Load and only if not `Page.IsPostback` to bind your GridView to it's datasource. Then use GridView's RowDataBound event to bind your DropDownList to it's DataSource. Besides, you don't need to iterate all GridView Rows in the SelectedIndexChanged event-handler. The sender **is** the DropDownList that was changed.

Comment: @Tim Thank you, this was really helpful i did what you said code below. but i need some data to bind on a label in the same gridview that is y i have SelectedIndexChanged event-handler. I am still having a little challenge i want to be able to bind data on labels in d row which d dropdownlist where a value was selected but what i have seem to bind to the label on the first row only, regardless of the dropdownlist that was selected. Any pointers??

Comment: This happens to most people...people leave the code to bind the gridview in page_load without any condition to check whether the page is a postback...You must ensure that you bind the gridview only if the page is not postback.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Dropdown1_selected Index changed...

User as following in aspx file....``

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClass" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("ClassName") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                       </EditItemTemplate>   
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

CS Class code behind in edit_event of Gridview..

DropDownList ddlClassName = (DropDownList) (DetailsGrid.Rows[index2].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlClass"));

string ClassNamevalue = ddlClassName.SelectedValue.Trim();